# Why is "Follow Active Quads" distorting neighboring faces?

Tags: uv, faces

I have seen basically no one discuss this at all. I'm trying to use follow active quads to unwrap this model in a pixel-perfect manner. Follow active quads has always worked for me before, however after 4.0 it seems to not work anymore. Is this intentional? It just warps unselected neighboring uvs and I obviously don't want it to. I've seen no one else discuss this, I'm so confused I just want to unwrap this model but it's been weeks and I've seen no one discuss this. [image: On the left is the face before unwrapped, right is after. Notice how the brick floor becomes distorted despite not being selected]

Comment: You need to select a face that is square if you want the unwrap to be orthogonal, if it doesn't work please share your object

Comment: @moonboots I just checked the behavior with a similar object. The problem in 4.0 is, if you select just parts of the mesh and unwrap them again, the new UV islands keep the connections to the islands which they share vertices with instead of separating them. This was not the case in 3.6, there the new islands were separate. In 4.0 you can only achieve that by moving the selected faces away from the others beforehand (only in _UV editor's_ _Face Select_ mode!) so they are disconnected, then unwrap them. Don't know if this is a bug or supposed to be like that, could not find a bug report though.

Comment: I think I've noticed something similar, pretty bad idea imho